# Log4Net: Enumerating GlobalContext properties?

Tags: log4net

I'm trying to utilize the Loggly appender utility for log4net. 
I've found that their code is enumerating through the `ThreadContext` properties and appending them to the payload getting sent over the wire to the loggly service. Good idea! However, the same feature is not being applied to the `GlobalContext` properties. Figuring this was a miss on their part I tried my hand at enumerating through the `GlobalContext` properties and adding these to the payload as well.

However, this has proven to be a problem. There doesn't appear to be any way to access the keys and associated values as the `ThreadContext` properties are accessed.

How can the `GlobalContext` properties be enumerated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I see would be to retrieve the properties class for the global context (`GlobalContext.Properties` which returns a `GlobalContextProperties` class) and get the `ReadOnlyPropertiesDictionary` returned by the internal method `GetReadOnlyProperties()` through reflection. Once you have the `ReadOnlyPropertiesDictionary` you can iterate on keys and values

From what I see the `ThreadContext` has more or less the same mechanism so you could take example on the `ThreadContext` enumeration to port it to the `GlobalContext`.

Comment: Yeah, I came to a similar solution. Found it sorta odd to not see like functionally between global and thread context properties.