# How to configure an appender to log all log4net ThreadContext/GlobalContext/LogicalThreadContext properties?

Tags: c#, json, log4net, log4net-appender

How to configure an appender to log all log4net ThreadContext/GlobalContext/LogicalThreadContext properties?

I would like to use custom properties in my application and log everything into a textfile. Every logmessage should be a valid JSON-Object.

I would like to include all properties from the different Context-Objects (Thread/LogicalThread/MDC/Global). But all examples I find need the knowledge of the property-key.

I found an answer which leads me to the thought, that this is not possible with the API at all:
[Log4Net: Enumerating GlobalContext properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29448768/log4net-enumerating-globalcontext-properties)

If there is no official way to do this, would [this code](https://github.com/Litee/log4net.Layout.Json/blob/master/src/log4net.Layout.Json/JsonLayout.cs) point to the correct direction?

[log4net.ext.json](https://sourceforge.net/p/log4net-json/wiki/first%20steps/) seems to ignore the context-properties

Answer (score 1):

simply just use below conversion pattern, the [%property] would cover all the properties in the context.

```
%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property] - %message%newline
```

For JSON object, then you need to write your own converter.

Answer (score 0):

With [log4net.Ext.Json](https://github.com/BrightOpen/log4net.Ext.Json/), one could use the `property` member:

```
<appender...>
    <layout type='log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json'>
        <decorator type='log4net.Layout.Decorators.StandardTypesDecorator, log4net.Ext.Json' />
        <default /> <!--explicit default members-->
        <member value='property' />
    </layout> 
</appender>
```